# Don't remove compound letter (alphabet) from list of stopwords (en) in R

Tags: r

I want to keep the alphabets associated with "-" when we apply StopWords:

```r
ovid <- tm_map(ovid, removeWords, stopwords('en'))
```

I have in input:

- "the k-means clustering",
- "e-marketing and social media"

I have results in output: "-means clustering, "-marketing social media" 
I want to have in output "k-means clustering", "e-marketing social media"

Comment: that is just reinventing the wheel. You will have to improvise the stopwords so as to ensure those words are not picked. Check whether there is a parameter to do that.

Comment: Probably, you need to remove them using some other functions. Can you add `dput(ovid)` ?